# Updating tableview from the internet on Iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am doing an iphone app using a storyboard on xcode and on one of my tableviews I would like to display the english premier league table which I will load from a file or a database on to the table view. my question is how i can connect this table to the internet so it can update the team positions every week after they play? what is this action called is it RSS feed or ftp push? some people are using Json and a database but this is too confusing for me as I am very new in this field. I would like to know what guys think and will be greatful for your answers. Thanks in advance! Stan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is easy and ubiquitous if you use web services with iOS. It will make it easier for you to display results in table form too.

I would think about defining the teams as Core Data objects. You might want to make objects for Division and Team (sorry if the terminology is wrong, don't know a lot about EPL) to allow for teams being relegated or moving up. In each Division you would have a relationship of teams, so you could display the ladder for any division just by fetching the Division object from core data and then getting a NSSet of all the teams with division.teams.

Then you fetch the information about the teams. Probably you would receive a JSON feed with information about each team. You would parse the received data using NSJSONSerialization (built into iOS) and store it in Core Data.

You could use [RestKit](http://restkit.org), which can handle the network requests and map received JSON directly to Core Data if you spend a bit of time configuring it. Or you could use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) if you prefer to do the parsing yourself.

To display the data you could use a NSFetchedResultsController. Once you have set up the query and done the initial fetch you connect the table view to it, and the ladder is displayed. NSFetchedResultsController requires a sort descriptor - it would probably be ladder ranking in your case. Setting the view controller containing the table view as the delegate for the NSFetchedResultsController.

Doing the periodic update is easy. Whenever your app enters the foreground you do a check of the timestamp on your Core Data objects and see if it is old enough for you to kick off a refresh (or just store a simple NSDate string somewhere, like NSUserDefaults, whenever you do a fetch). If it is, do the fetch/parse/update cycle again - your table updates automatically because the NSFetchedResultsController will be notified that the underlying data has changed and it will cause the table to refresh.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, i will have a look into it and try to implement it.